# Pimcore /install is redirecting again and again

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, pimcore-v5

Installed Pimcore5.1, PHP7 and extensions, MySQL, Nginx

Nginx Virtual Host config is as:

```
upstream php-pimcore5 {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name s3pim.local;
    root /var/www/html/s3pim/web;
    index app.php index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # Pimcore Head-Link Cache-Busting
    rewrite ^/cache-buster-(?:\d+)/(.*) /$1 last;

    # Stay secure
    #
    # a) don't allow PHP in folders allowing file uploads
    location ~* /var/assets/*\.php(/|$) {
        return 404;
    }
    # b) Prevent clients from accessing hidden files (starting with a dot)
    # Access to `/.well-known/` is allowed.
    # https://www.mnot.net/blog/2010/04/07/well-known
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known/) {
        deny all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    # c) Prevent clients from accessing to backup/config/source files
    location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|conf(ig)?|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Some Admin Modules need this:
    # Database Admin, Server Info
    location ~* ^/admin/(adminer|external) {
        rewrite .* /app.php$is_args$args last;
    }

    # Thumbnails
    location ~* .*/(image|video)-thumb__\d+__.* {
        try_files /var/tmp/$1-thumbnails$request_uri /app.php;
location ~* .*/(image|video)-thumb__\d+__.* {
        try_files /var/tmp/$1-thumbnails$request_uri /app.php;
        expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Assets
    # Still use a whitelist approach to prevent each and every missing asset to go through the PHP Engine.
    location ~* (.+?)\.((?:css|js)(?:\.map)?|jpe?g|gif|png|svgz?|eps|exe|gz|zip|mp\d|ogg|ogv|webm|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?)$ {
        try_files /var/assets$uri $uri =404;
        expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Installer
    # Remove this if you don't need the web installer (anymore)
    if (-f $document_root/install.php) {
        rewrite ^/install(/?.*) /install.php$1 last;
    }

    location / {
        error_page 404 /meta/404;
        add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=edge";
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Use this location when the installer has to be run
    # location ~ /(app|install)\.php(/|$) {
    #
    # Use this after initial install is done:
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        send_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
        # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
        # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

        # Activate these, if using Symlinks and opcache
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # PHP-FPM Status and Ping
    location /fpm- {
        access_log off;
        include fastcgi_params;
        location /fpm-status {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            # add additional IP's or Ranges
            deny all;
            fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        }
        location /fpm-ping {
            fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        }
    }
    # nginx Status
    # see: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html
#    location /nginx-status {
#        allow 127.0.0.1;
#        deny all;
#        access_log off;
#        stub_status;
#    }
}
```

Excluded .htaccess file, start PHP FPM, Start Nginx

Now when hitting s3pim.local, it redirects to s3pim.local/install which redirects to s3pim.local/install/ which redirects to s3pim.local/install and so on..

If in install.php I write some code and die then that code get printed. Its all occuring where it is

```
$response->send
```

in Project_Root/web/install.php that is redirecting it again and again on install php.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you have to uncomment following line:

```
# location ~ /(app|install)\.php(/|$) {
```

And comment one below:

```
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
```

Remember to undo this after installation succeeds.

In the end, your file should look like this:

```
upstream php-pimcore5 {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name s3pim.local;
    root /var/www/html/s3pim/web;
    index app.php index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    # Pimcore Head-Link Cache-Busting
    rewrite ^/cache-buster-(?:\d+)/(.*) /$1 last;

    # Stay secure
    #
    # a) don't allow PHP in folders allowing file uploads
    location ~* /var/assets/*\.php(/|$) {
        return 404;
    }

    # b) Prevent clients from accessing hidden files (starting with a dot)
    # Access to `/.well-known/` is allowed.
    # https://www.mnot.net/blog/2010/04/07/well-known
    # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785
    location ~* /\.(?!well-known/) {
        deny all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # c) Prevent clients from accessing to backup/config/source files
    location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|conf(ig)?|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Some Admin Modules need this:
    # Database Admin, Server Info
    location ~* ^/admin/(adminer|external) {
        rewrite .* /app.php$is_args$args last;
    }

    # Thumbnails
    location ~* .*/(image|video)-thumb__\d+__.* {
        try_files /var/tmp/$1-thumbnails$request_uri /app.php;
        expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Assets
    # Still use a whitelist approach to prevent each and every missing asset to go through the PHP Engine.
    location ~* (.+?)\.((?:css|js)(?:\.map)?|jpe?g|gif|png|svgz?|eps|exe|gz|zip|mp\d|ogg|ogv|webm|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?)$ {
        try_files /var/assets$uri $uri =404;
        expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Installer
    # Remove this if you don't need the web installer (anymore)
    if (-f $document_root/install.php) {
        rewrite ^/install(/?.*) /install.php$1 last;
    }

    location / {
        error_page 404 /meta/404;
        add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=edge";
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Use this location when the installer has to be run
    location ~ /(app|install)\.php(/|$) {
    #
    # Use this after initial install is done:
    # location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        send_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
        # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
        # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

        # Activate these, if using Symlinks and opcache
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```